# Cordova BarcodeScanner not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I'm using Ionic Framework with the BarcodeScanner [plugin](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/).

The BarcodeScanner is working fine on iPad and iPhone 4 running iOS7, but today I tested it on iPhone 5 and 6 running iOS8 and the scanner doesn't show up, neither shows any errors. This is the code I'm using in my controller, very simple.

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
            if (imageData.cancelled) {
                return;
            }

            console.log("We got a barcode" +
                "Result: " + imageData.text + "n" +
                "Format: " + imageData.format + "n" +
                "Cancelled: " + imageData.cancelled);

        }, function(error) {
            console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
```

I've been trying to research this issue for hours and haven't found anything yet.

Do you think I have to add some kind of permission to use the camera on iPhone? or something different?

Comment: I tried it on iPhone & iPad running IOS 8 and works fine .. are you sure about your JS code ?